# Remove from CollectionProperty

Tags: python, add-on

I am using the the `CollectionProperty` class to store a list of properties, so something like this:

```
class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Property Name", default="Something")
    value = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Property Name", default=22)

bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)
bpy.types.World.my_collection_prop = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)
```

Then in an `Operator` I am calling the `add()` method to create additional properties:

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    # some irrelevant code here...

    def execute(self, context):
        my_prop = context.world.my_collection_prop.add()
        my_prop.name = "test"
        my_prop.value = 123
```

Now my problem is doing the opposite of `add()`.

How do I go about removing an instance from a `CollectionProperty`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I was about to click the button to post this question, I realized maybe the `CollectionProperty` class extends/has the same methods as a dictionary or list. Anyway, with a little trial and error I found that it does (sort of).

To remove a single element:

```
context.world.my_collection_prop.remove(2)
```

To clear the whole collection:

```
context.world.my_collection_prop.clear()
```

I really don't understand how details like this get left out of the Blender API documentation.

Comment: And how to find the index of the element?

Comment: @mifth to remove one element you have to have it's index. This is usually possible when you are using for example id obtained from UIList from gui - when user click on an item, you'll got it's id. Other than that you have to search thru the whole collection for specified elements, or just operate on numbers less than the total len of the collection.

Comment: Related to this I just opened this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114190/missing-a-proper-documentation-for-collectionproperty
I also find it really annoying that the methods are not in the documentation.
Are just missing them and they are burried in some place?

Comment: 2.91 - it seems it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `CollectionProperty.find(name)` to find the index of the item to remove. Then remove the item with `remove(index)` method. For example:

```
def remove_item(collection, item):
     collection.remove(collection.find(item.name))
```

Then use like this:

```
remove_from_collection(context.world.my_collection, my_item)
```