# How to add/remove Properties to/from existing PropertyGroup in Blender 2.91?

Tags: python, properties

How to add/remove `bpy.props` `Properties` to/from existing `PropertyGroup` in Blender 2.91?

Let's say I've done the following:

```
import bpy

class MyProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    test1 : bpy.props.IntProperty()

bpy.utils.register_class(MyProps)
bpy.types.Object.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProps)
```

How can I add "test2" `IntProperty()` to `bpy.types.Object.my_props` after that? And how can I remove it afterwards if I need to? I've tried to find something inside `bpy.types.Object.my_props`,  `bpy.types.Object.my_props[1]['type']`, `bpy.context.object.my_props` - but there's nothing which would look like adding/removing methods.

Basically this is the same question as this:
[Remove from CollectionProperty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/remove-from-collectionproperty)
but the described solution doesn't work for 2.91 anymore. I can't find `.remove()`, `.clear()`, `.add()` and any similar method which would allow to dynamically add/remove Properties to/from existing registered `PropertyGroup`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello, you need to use a `CollectionProperty` instead of a `PointerProperty`. The methods in the question you provided still work, but they need a Collection property. A PointerProperty only links to a single PropertyGroup, and a CollectionProperty to a dynamic collection of props.

Comment: Thank you! I see my mistake now. It helps! )